# VBA application Ontime

Tags: vba, excel

I got some problem with application.ontime maybe somebody knows the solution

From the beggining

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  'some code
  call macro_name
end sub

sub macro_name
  'some code refreshing data on form
  call start_timer
end sub

dim start_time as date 

Sub start_timer()

    start_time = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime start_time, "macro_name"


End Sub

Sub end_timer()

    Application.OnTime start_time, "macro_name", , False
    'MsgBox "done"  i put this to be sure that code is executed 

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(cancel As Boolean)
  'some code  
  call end_timer
end sub
```

problem is that the timer doesn't stop. If i have some other workbook open and i close the one with ontime code it starts again at scheduled time

if i put buttons on a form

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
start_timer

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
end_timer
End Sub
```

everything works ok and ontime is canceled.

I solved it partly by putting the

```
call end_timer
```

on the form closing button

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()

    end_timer
    ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

but if workbook will be closed some other way than button ontime won't be canceled

sorry for my english i'll try to explain better if something is unclear

Comment: Given the code in the first block, it is apparent the timer will continue. You call `macro_name` from your sub `start_timer`, and `start_timer` in turn calls `macro_name`. If you put in no logic to end that, you create a cycle that will continue on in perpetuity.

Comment: But i cancel on time in "befor_close event". 
I got another file with same on time proc and it works perfect (it must be almoast the same becouse in this one it doesn't work :) )

Comment: But you don't close the workbook in either of those procedures, so that event would never fire.

Comment: it fires. I checked it with the msgbox, but when the "call end_timer" is placed in "befor_close event" it simply doesn't cancel the ontime, don't know why. There is no error it just go through all the lines and close workbook, but ontime is not canceled. It fires again in scheduled time.   
Thats why i placed it in "Private Sub Image1_Click()". Now it works, ontime is canceld and doesn't fire again. 
But when the workbook will be closed in some other way than click in the image then the end_timer won't fire and that's bad.

Comment: I don't understand how that can be given the code you supplied.